Dell R730 Server giving ambiguous CPU0704 Machine Check Error
I have a Dell R730 Server I've been using as a Proxmox host, and I've suddenly gotten an error showing "CPU0704: CPU 2 Machine Check Error Detected." in the logs. This is a trigger for iDRAC to reboot the machine, and it shows a warning on the screen after the reboot that there was a machine check error (I can't get it to show on screen anymore.)
It did not used to do this before, and it seems to be happening at random. I tried to reset my system time as it seemed at first that this only occurred at midnight, but then it failed Mid-day and seems unrelated to the time. The logs show four to five "An OEM Diagnostic Event occurred." in the logs before the 0704 error.
All the research I've done online seems to show mixed advice on what this error even is, let alone what to

While I still have not figured out all the details, I have discovered what this error is TRYING to say and some troubleshooting steps to follow if you receive it.

WHAT is it?
Dell describes the error as "usually not an error of the CPU itself. But an indication that the CPU has detected an error in the system, or received an erroneous instruction from a system component. It is caused by a non-CPU event, such as a firmware mismatch, a system BUS interruption or a memory read/write interruption. The error can theoretically be caused by ANY system component, software, or hardware." (Dell PowerEdge: Resolve CPU 1 or 2 has an internal error (CPU IERR) on Servers)

I.E, something causing a communication error within the subsystems that CPU2 controls flagged this error. Despite the description from Dell however, an error with the CPU itself (like crashing from power saving settings) can cause this error. it just usually is not caused by the CPU and the error is not triggered by a CPU issue.

How can I even diagnose this?
This error can flag for several different things and can be caused by different components. It is saying that the error is with CPU2, and since this is a 2 CPU server we can rule out the error being related to any component driven by or connected to CPU1. So, now we should be looking at memory controllers, memory (RAM) PCIe slots, and anything else connected to CPU 2, AS WELL as CPU 2 itself.

I began troubleshooting by updating BIOS and iDRAC, as recommended in the KB article linked above. I also unplugged the system, held the button for 20 seconds, and powered back on - but unfortunately this was not the cause.
This is where, if the system was under warranty, you'd send it back to Dell and get them to handle it. Mine was a recycled server, and that of course was not an option. However, please be aware I am just a novice user learning to manage these devices 'by doing', and I don't recommend following this troubleshooting any further if you don't know what you are doing. You may be dealing with hardware failure at this point, and there is no guarantee these next steps will help.
From here, someone on and old forum recommended disabling C1E states in the BIOS (I can not find this post anymore, apologies) but this did not help anyway after I did it. I ran hardware diagnostics (the full, 1 hour plus one) but it found nothing. I now decided that I had nothing to lose, and yanked the behemoth R730 from my rack and pulled the CPU heat-sink for CPU 2. I pulled out all the memory I had installed for CPU2, and left it out suspecting that IT was the real problem I was dealing with. But for good measure I also pulled the CPU out and cleaned the heat sink and the heat spreader, replaced the thermal paste, and re-seated it.
This seemed to help, but no fix. I spoke with a technician I work with, and he recommended Choosing the "Performance" server profile, Enabling C1E and disabling C states on my machine. (Here was his source for the C1E and C states: https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/poweredge-hardware-general/cpu0704-cpu1cpu2-machine-check-error-detected-on-front-lcd-panel/647f6e8ff4ccf8a8debe938a)
The TRUE fix for my issue was disabling C1E states in the BIOS - and the reason this ended up being the fix was because these are the "high end" CPU's for Broadwell Era Xeons (E5 2689 v4) and they do not do well with any sort of power saving/frequency limiting settings. I've now had the system up and running for over a month, and the error now has not popped back up.
LONG STORY SHORT - If you've tried everything and you STILL are not able to address this issue, Enable Performance Mode, Enable C1E states, and disable C states (and any other power saving features). If you're STILL experiencing the issue, it may be time to look into a CPU replacement, or some more advanced troubleshooting. But if you're seeing symptoms like mine where it gives you very little additional information, you may only need to re-seat things to get back up and running!
